# How do I increase the font in Mozilla Firefox without a mouse?

Tags: firefox, keyboard-shortcuts, fonts, zoom

I just downloaded Firefox but my mouse is dead.  And it seems you can only increase the font of a web page by first dragging the "zoom" button to the toolbar and then using it.  Is there any way to increase the size with just a keyboard?

Win 7 Pro.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> together with <kbd>+</kbd>, <kbd>-</kbd> and <kbd>0</kbd> to increase, decrease and reset site zoom.

Answer (score 10):

Commands:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>+</kbd> to zoom
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>-</kbd> to zoom out
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>0</kbd> to reset